# CMake, OSX, the @rpath, and linking to frameworks

Tags: macos, hyperlink, cmake, frameworks, rpath

I've spent a week trying to get something that I got working on Linux to work on OSX, but to no avail. I've tried reading the CMake article on the rpath and various other SO posts regarding it and mucking about with my CMakeLists.txt to get it to work, but I've failed and I'm hoping someone could give me some hints here on what I'm doing wrong.

```
# CMake 2.8.11 and above required for linking to qtmain.lib library on Windows
# CMake 2.8.12 and above required for MACOSX_RPATH property
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
set(PROJECT_NAME "maya_standalone_test")

if(APPLE)
    message(STATUS "Setting MacOSX SDK...")
    set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk")
endif(APPLE)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules)

# Attempt to find existing installation of Maya and define variables
find_package(Maya REQUIRED)

# Add include search paths
include_directories(
  ${MAYA_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

if(APPLE)
    message(STATUS "Setting OSX Framework path to: ${MAYA_LOCATION}/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks")
    set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK FIRST)
    set(CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH "${MAYA_LOCATION}/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks")
endif(APPLE)

# Set compiler flags for each platform
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    message(STATUS "Detected compiler as Clang...")
    # Using Clang 
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ \
                        -std=c++0x \
                        -fno-gnu-keywords \
                        -fpascal-strings \
                        -O3 \
                        -dynamic")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ggdb -glldb")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ \
                                -std=c++0x \
                                -fno-gnu-keywords \
                                -fpascal-strings \
                                -O3 \
                                -Wl, \
                                -headerpad_max_install_names \
                                -dynamic")

elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    # using GCC on Linux
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-DBits64_ \
                      -m64 \
                      -DUNIX \
                      -D_BOOL \
                      -DLINUX \
                      -DFUNCPROTO \
                      -D_GNU_SOURCE \
                      -DLINUX_64 \
                      -fPIC \
                      -fno-strict-aliasing \
                      -DREQUIRE_IOSTREAM \
                      -O3 \
                      -Wall \
                      -Wno-multichar \
                      -Wno-comment \
                      -Wno-sign-compare \
                      -funsigned-char \
                      -pthread")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} \
                        -Wno-deprecated \
                        -Wno-reorder \
                        -ftemplate-depth-25 \
                        -fno-gnu-keywords")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ggdb")

elseif(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    # using Visual Studio C++
    # TODO: Need to find the compiler flags 
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/MP")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MP /ZI /EHsc")
endif()

# Add project sources
add_subdirectory(src)

# Don't skip the full RPATH for the build/install tree
set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

if(APPLE)
    message (STATUS "Setting OSX-specific settings...")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR}")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR "@rpath")
else()
    # Disable RPATH stripping during installation so that the binary will link correctly
    # to the Maya libs
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
endif(APPLE)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
add_executable (${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

# Set preprocessor definitions
set_target_properties(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${MAYA_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")

# Link the executable to the libraries
message(STATUS "Linking to Maya libraries at: ${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${MAYA_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

The resulting executable, when I check with otool, gives me:

```
Load command 41
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 72
         path /Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/MacOS (offset 12)
```

Which is correct, but the library paths are:

```
../bin/maya_standalone_test:
    @executable_path/libOpenMaya.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libOpenMayaAnim.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libOpenMayaFX.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libOpenMayaRender.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libOpenMayaUI.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libFoundation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libclew.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libAnimSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libDeformSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libModifiers.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libDynSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libKinSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libModelSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libNurbsSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libPolySlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libProjectSlice.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libImage.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libShared.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libTranslators.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libDataModel.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libRenderModel.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libNurbsEngine.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libDependEngine.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libCommandEngine.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @executable_path/libIMFbase.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 104.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

And of course, when I run the application, I then get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/libOpenMaya.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sonictk/Git/experiments/maya_standalone_app_example/build/../bin/maya_standalone_test
  Reason: image not found
[1]    16909 trace trap  ../bin/maya_standalone_test
```

I tried having a post build command to change the @executable_path to @rpath instead for each library, but while that got the libraries found, I then had issues with the executable not being able to find the frameworks (located at `${MAYA_LOCATION}/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks`) and other issues linking to other dynamic libs in the same folder (such as Maya's QtCore, etc.)

This all works, of course, if I copy the `Frameworks/` folder to the parent directory of my executable and all files from `${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR}` to the same folder as the executable, or if I set the `DYLD_LIBARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` to point to the library and framework directoies before launching my executable. But I would like these libraries and frameworks on OSX to be dynamically linked without having to modify the environment, like I do on Linux.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Just a note that you might want to do `list(APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH ${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR})` instead, which appends to any existing contents of `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` instead of overwriting them. Similarly for `CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH`